# Android Studio: Font changing error

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview

So I have two objects on my activity, a TextView, and a Button. I did change the font of both of these using a font style from my assets folder. The project would load fine no problems. However now all of a sudden changing the TextView font makes the game crash and not load. I can't understand what could have caused this and how to solve it other than maybe using a button to display text, which is in practical.

My java code:

```
public class Main_Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__menu);
        Button n=(Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Stencil WW.ttf");
        n.setText("Start");
        n.setTypeface(typeface);
        Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Stencil WW.ttf");
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setTypeface(typeface2);
        //sets screen orientation on created
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

I did use the typeface to change both texts fonts but I tried just making it again with typeface2 and it still crashes. Not sure if I need to show any other part of my project but will if you wish to see it. Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: can you clarify which line is the 31?

Comment: title.setTypeface(typeface2);

Comment: the line that is doing the font change of the textview itself. this worked before.

Comment: ok, im going for a blind shoot since is a nullpointer. are you sure the textview in the XML is named R.id.title?

Comment: android:id="@+id/title"

Comment: the id inside xml

Comment: you dont have two xml?, the one on the on create is "activity_main__menu" with two "_"

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean but that is the name of my layout? btw i just tried with a button text and it still gets the same error

Comment: im not sure you are using the right xml on your activity, because that kind of error happend went the activity cant find the id of your view in the xml you are giving in the setContentView method

Comment: this is the only activity i have.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot "setText" to the title

Comment: the setText should not be needed to change the font of the textview, it worked before fine without it and i dont see how that could effect the changing the font?